# Downgrading from 14.04LTS to 12.04LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I was using ubuntu 12.04 and upgraded to 14.04 32-bit system. I don't like the 14.04 because it's not very stable. How can I downgrade back to 12.04LTS?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto

Comment: Unfortunately, 12.04 will be going out of support fairly soon (April of 2017). If anything, it may be worth your while to do a clean install of 14.04, or wait just two more months for 16.04 when the next LTS comes out. You can't blame 14.04 being unstable when you did an upgrade between two releases that are two years apart.

Answer (score 2):

No option to downgrading from 14.04 to 12.04. The only way would be to re-install 12.04 over the top of 14.04 thereby over-writing everything.

Before doing re-install save your data and then load on to 12-04.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd do a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.3. Your stability problems are likely caused by problems occurring during the upgrade, as 14.04 is, in general, very stable.

Unfortunately, there is no way to downgrade an Ubuntu system online. The internal procedure for upgrading an already-installed system is quite complex, and reversing this process would be far, far more complex, and is not supported. A fresh install is always the best option. Additionally, Ubuntu 12.04 will only be supported until spring of 2017, so it would not be recommend to fresh-install 12.04 at this time.

You may want to wait two more months and fresh-install Ubuntu 16.04 instead.